# Variável reseta sempre que passa para um método

Tags: java, variáveis, método

Estou a fazer um programa simples que insere na primeira possível posição de um vetor, uma `String`.

Este é o código que tenho:

```
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author AmândioMagalhães(115
 */
public class PL7_ex6 {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Formatter output = new Formatter(System.out);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] visitantes = new String[100];
        int nElm = 0;
        menu(visitantes, nElm);

    }

    private static void menu(String[] vec, int nElm) {
        int op;
        output.format("bem-vindo!");
        output.format("\n\nAqui pode:");
        do {
            System.out.println("\n\n1 - Inserir um visitante"
                    + "\n2 - Listar todos os visitantes"
                    + "\n3 - Atualizar um nome dado"
                    + "\n4 - Eliminar um visitante dado"
                    + "\n5- Lisstar os nomes começados por uma dada letra"
                    + "\n6 - Listar nomes repetidos"
                    + "\n0 - para terminar o programa");
            op = input.nextInt();
            if (op < 0 || op > 6) {
                output.format("%sTem de introduzir uma opção válida!");
            }

            if (op == 0) {
                //termina
            } else {
                switch (op) {
                    case 0:

                    case 1:
                        inserirVisitante(vec, nElm);
                        System.out.println(vec[0]);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        listarVisitantes(vec, nElm);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new AssertionError();
                }
            }
        } while (op > 0 || op > 6);

    }


    private static void inserirVisitante(String[] vec, int nElm) {
        int pos = 0;
        int i = 0;
        if (nElm == vec.length) {
            output.format("Não há espaço disponível :(");
        } else {
            do {
                if (i == nElm - 1) {
                    pos = i;
                }
                i++;
            } while (i >= nElm - 1);
            System.out.println("Introduza o nome do visitante");
            input.nextLine();
            vec[pos] = input.nextLine();
            vec[pos].trim();
            nElm = nElm + 1;
            //para testar
            System.out.println("\n" + nElm + "\n");
        }
    }

    //nElem não passa de inserirVisitantes para este método
    private static void listarVisitantes(String[] vec, int nElm) {
        if (nElm == 0) {
            //para testar
            System.out.println("\n" + nElm + "\n");
            output.format("Não há visitantes.");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < nElm; i++) {
                output.format("%n%d", vec[i]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

O problema aqui é que a variável `nElm` *reseta* para 0 sem eu a definir como 0

Comment: Tu das o valor da variavel nElm na linha 2 depois do public static void main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se quer manter o estado da variável entre os métodos precisa mandar e receber. Seria assim:

```
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author AmândioMagalhães(115
 */
public class PL7_ex6 {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Formatter output = new Formatter(System.out);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] visitantes = new String[100];
        int nElm = 0;
        menu(visitantes, nElm);

    }

    private static void menu(String[] vec, int nElm) {
        int op;
        output.format("bem-vindo!");
        output.format("\n\nAqui pode:");
        do {
            System.out.println("\n\n1 - Inserir um visitante"
                    + "\n2 - Listar todos os visitantes"
                    + "\n3 - Atualizar um nome dado"
                    + "\n4 - Eliminar um visitante dado"
                    + "\n5- Lisstar os nomes começados por uma dada letra"
                    + "\n6 - Listar nomes repetidos"
                    + "\n0 - para terminar o programa");
            op = input.nextInt();
            if (op < 0 || op > 6) {
                output.format("%sTem de introduzir uma opção válida!");
            }

            if (op == 0) {
                //termina
            } else {
                switch (op) {
                    case 0:

                    case 1:
                        nElm = inserirVisitante(vec, nElm);
                        System.out.println(vec[0]);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        listarVisitantes(vec, nElm);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new AssertionError();
                }
            }
        } while (op > 0 || op > 6);

    }


    private static int inserirVisitante(String[] vec, int nElm) {
        int pos = 0;
        int i = 0;
        if (nElm == vec.length) {
            output.format("Não há espaço disponível :(");
        } else {
            do {
                if (i == nElm - 1) {
                    pos = i;
                }
                i++;
            } while (i >= nElm - 1);
            System.out.println("Introduza o nome do visitante");
            input.nextLine();
            vec[pos] = input.nextLine();
            vec[pos].trim();
            nElm = nElm + 1;
            //para testar
            System.out.println("\n" + nElm + "\n");
            return eElm;
        }
    }

    //nElem não passa de inserirVisitantes para este método
    private static void listarVisitantes(String[] vec, int nElm) {
        if (nElm == 0) {
            //para testar
            System.out.println("\n" + nElm + "\n");
            output.format("Não há visitantes.");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < nElm; i++) {
                output.format("%n%d", vec[i]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Mas o ideal seria ter essas informações na classe e poder acessá-las em todos os métodos de forma direta sem ter que haver comunicação. Não é o ideal fazer da forma como fez, mas já é uma melhora. O código ainda tem outros erros. Eu consertei vários deles, forma tantos que nem lembro da maioria, mas já ajuda.

```
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PL7_ex6 {
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Formatter output = new Formatter(System.out);
    private static String[] visitantes = new String[100];
    private static int nElm = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        output.format("bem-vindo!");
        output.format("\n\nAqui pode:");
        int op;
        do {
            System.out.println("\n\n1 - Inserir um visitante"
                    + "\n2 - Listar todos os visitantes"
                    + "\n3 - Atualizar um nome dado"
                    + "\n4 - Eliminar um visitante dado"
                    + "\n5- Lisstar os nomes começados por uma dada letra"
                    + "\n6 - Listar nomes repetidos"
                    + "\n0 - para terminar o programa");
            op = input.nextInt();
            if (op < 0 || op > 6) {
                output.format("%sTem de introduzir uma opção válida!");
                continue;
            }
             switch (op) {
                case 1:
                    inserirVisitante();
                    System.out.println(visitantes[0]); //por que tem isso?
                    break;
                case 2:
                    listarVisitantes();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new AssertionError(); //não deveria fazer isso
            }
        } while (op != 0);
    }

    private static void inserirVisitante() {
        int pos = 0;
        int i = 0;
        if (nElm == visitantes.length) {
            output.format("Não há espaço disponível :(");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Introduza o nome do visitante");
            visitantes[nElm++] = input.nextLine().trim();
            //para testar
            System.out.println("\n" + nElm + "\n");
        }
        return;
    }

    private static void listarVisitantes() {
        if (nElm == 0) {
            //para testar
            System.out.println("\n" + nElm + "\n");
            output.format("Não há visitantes.");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < nElm; i++) {
                output.format("%n%d", visitantes[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/CommonMember.java).

Answer (score 0):

A questão é que o java perde a referencia da variável, logo que executada no método em outras palavras seria dizer que o `nElm` que defines no método main não é o mesmo que é processado dentro do `inserirVisitante`, mas sim uma referencia. Por isso que não é possível usar.

Dai que a melhor forma é declarar as variáveis como estáticas fora do escopo

E o facto do objecto estar nElm estar dentro do metodo main, ele perde valores logo que o inserirVisitante termina de executar.

Assim:

```
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PL7_ex6 {
private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private static Formatter output = new Formatter(System.out);
private static String[] visitantes;
private static int nElm;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    visitantes = new String[100];
    nElm = 0;
    menu();

}

private static void menu() {
    int op;
    output.format("bem-vindo!");
    output.format("\n\nAqui pode:");
    do {
        System.out.println("\n\n1 - Inserir um visitante"
                + "\n2 - Listar todos os visitantes"
                + "\n3 - Atualizar um nome dado"
                + "\n4 - Eliminar um visitante dado"
                + "\n5- Lisstar os nomes começados por uma dada letra"
                + "\n6 - Listar nomes repetidos"
                + "\n0 - para terminar o programa");
        op = input.nextInt();
        if (op < 0 || op > 6) {
            output.format("%sTem de introduzir uma opção válida!");
        }

        if (op == 0) {
            //termina
        } else {
            switch (op) {
                case 0:

                case 1:
                    inserirVisitante();
                    System.out.println(visitantes[0]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    listarVisitantes();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new AssertionError();
            }
        }
    } while (op > 0 || op > 6);

}


private static void inserirVisitante() {
    int pos = 0;
    int i = 0;
    if (nElm == visitantes.length) {
        output.format("Não há espaço disponível :(");
    } else {
        do {
            if (i == nElm - 1) {
                pos = i;
            }
            i++;
        } while (i >= nElm - 1);
        System.out.println("Introduza o nome do visitante");
        input.nextLine();
        visitantes[pos] = input.nextLine();
        visitantes[pos].trim();
        nElm = nElm + 1;
        //para testar
        System.out.println("\n" + nElm + "\n");
    }
}

//nElem não passa de inserirVisitantes para este método
private static void listarVisitantes() {
    if (nElm == 0) {
        //para testar
        System.out.println("\n" + nElm + "\n");
        output.format("Não há visitantes.");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < nElm; i++) {
            output.format("%n%d", vec[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

}